# haml collection and nil --> strftime

Tags: ruby, conditional-statements, haml, null, strftime

I have a Post object I am rendering in a partial, where one element is

```
= post.created_at
```

I want to format the time so I've tried variations of strftime in the partial and as a model hook.

```
= post.created_at.strftime('etc etc')
&
= post.formatted_time
```

These work fine when there is something to render, but when there isn't a set of posts, there is an error rendering the page:

```
undefined method `strftime' for nil:NilClass
```

only the first works when there are no posts, and creates 1 empty post div on the page.

I need to do something either in the model or template to catch when it is empty and render nothing, which seems basic but I've not yet struck the right search terms to find something I understand to implement.

I'm posting this so someone might help me to think through what I've got so far. Basically I need to format time, which I can do but catch when there is nothing to format.

Answer (score 2):

In Rails you can always use `try`, which will run the method only if created_at is not nil:

```
= post.created_at.try(:strftime, 'etc etc')
```

http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try